# Amazon RDS, lambda postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can I use psycopg2 for connect to RDS postgres in AWS Lambda?
What permissions should I set for that?

Answer (score 3):

```
import boto3

rds = boto3.client('rds')

for line in rds.describe_db_instances():
    print (line)
```

Comment: @FelixSFD Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use psycopg2 to in AWS Lambda, but you have to add the lib in the [Lambda Zip](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/) or You can use [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/) to do that.

You should attach RDS permissions to your Lambda.